# Can't get .live on keydown working... any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, live

I tried using .on instead, and delegate, none of them worked. (code works when not live)
Can anyone give me a hand here? I'm looping out a list (via ajax request) with the class of "qspholder" and this code should allow me to select and click items on the list using the arrow keys and enter. Yet for some reason I just cannot seem to get this working when I try to do it as live. I put it (the list) in a div with .html(data) after submitting and retrieving the values. This code is not on the page it is being loaded from, it's on the page I am loading it to. Can anyone give me some advice as to how I get this working? Thank you.

```
$(window).live("keydown", function(e){
        var liSelected;
        var li = $('.qspholder');
        $('.qspholder').removeClass('selected');
        if(e.which === 40){
            if(liSelected){
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.next();
                if(next.length > 0){
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                }else{
                    liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                }
            }else{
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        }else if(e.which === 38){
            $('.qspholder').removeClass('selected');
            if(liSelected){
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.prev();
                if(next.length > 0){
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                }else{
                    liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                }
            }else{
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if(e.which === 13) {
            liSelected.click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the advantage of keeping keyboard functions inside a `live()`? I normally don't do that, and it works fine (even with AJAX-elements on the page).

Comment: if you remove/move an element that has an `onclick` for example, the event will be remove and will not fire. with `.live`, the even keeps living even if the element was moved, replaced etc.

Comment: what is purpose using "live" here? I hope, a HTML document cannot have multiple window/document.! You can simply use $(document).keydown(function(){})??

Comment: @Bharath i agree with you, there is no use for the `.live` here, since this is an event the is connected to the document and not to an element.

Comment: @Nix - made an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KH8ZR/12/

Comment: @Dementic I know what `.live()` does, but I just can't see the advantage of putting **keyboard** actions inside it, as `document` will never be removed from the DOM. I have heard, that performance wise, it might in some cases be better to put onclick events inside `on()`, but is it really a benefit when you are targeting the `document` directly?

Comment: @Nix simply put, no. there are some `code hidders` that replaces the document with some other code "For Security", i know it is bullshit, but some people use those. that is the only case i could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works, apply it to your code

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){alert(e.keyCode);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KBPb4/10/

applied to your original code ( also changed the `IF` to `SWITCH` )

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    var liSelected;
    var li = $('.qspholder');
    $('.qspholder').removeClass('selected');

    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 40:
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
        break;
    case 38:
        $('.qspholder').removeClass('selected');
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
        break;
    case 13:
        liSelected.click();
        break;
    }
});
```